# TranslateY() and TranslateX() animations working well in Chrome but not in FireFox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, animation

I've made an application that has CSS animations as shown below:

```
.hand
{
  position:fixed;
  top:-60%;
  left:50%;
  width:20%;
  margin-left:-10%;
}

.handmovedown
{
  transform: translateY(110%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(110%); /** Safari & Chrome **/
  -o-transform: translateY(110%); /** Opera **/
  -moz-transform: translateY(110%); /** Firefox **/
}

.objecttransition
{
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear; /** Chrome & Safari **/
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear; /** Firefox **/
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear; /** Opera **/
}

<img  id='Hand'  class="hand objecttransition"  src="css/images/hand.gif">
```

Now all of this runs more than fine in Chrome. Smooth and everything. But in FireFox its very slow and chunky. I'm really not sure what to do now? When I started googling I saw people mention KeyFrames? What is the benefit of using this vs trnaslate? What is the best way to deal with this?